# Professional templates pack in LibreOffice

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, templates

I have installed the [Professional Template Pack II - English](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/TemplatePack_II) OpenOffice.org extension in LibreOffice 3.5.5.3 on Windows 7. However, when I try to select a template, I don't see anything new. Is the extension simply incompatible or am I missing something?

If this extension is unusable, can you recommend an alternative, even if it's commercial? I want to avoid digging through a ton of mediocre community templates to find ones that are suitable for professional use. I would use Microsoft Office but I prefer the UI and file formats of LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of LibreOffice come with a few nice templates.